# Option fields in Scala

Tags: scala, monads, option-type

I have 2 RDD's that I joined them together using left join. As a result, the fields of the right RDD are now defined as Option as they might be None (null). when writing the result to a file it looks something like this: Some(value) for example: Some('value1'), Some('Value2').
How can I remove the 'Some' / remove the Option from the field definition?

Comment: Everyone is talking of RDDs lately. Are they a new addition to the Scala stdlib?

Answer (score 3):

If you have an `Option[String]` and turn this into a `String`, you still need to handle the case where your value is `None`.

For example you can turn `None`'s into empty strings:

```
val myInput: Option[String] = ...
val myOutput: String = myInput.getOrElse("")
```

Or into `null`'s:

```
val myInput: Option[String] = ...
val myOutput: String = myInput.orNull
```

Or not write them at all:

```
val myInput: Option[String] = ...
// Does nothing if myInput is None
myInput.foreach(writeToFile)
```

Comment: As an aside, `.getOrElse(null)` can be written as `.orNull`.